# issue with horizontal menu

Tags: css, iphone, flexbox, responsive

the issue with horizontal menu.desktop & Android device showing proper but issue with iPhone only.

```
ul.mobile_biz_tab{
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-moz-flex;
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar; 
    width: 100%;
}
ul.mobile_biz_tab > li {
    -webkit-flex:auto;
    -webkit-box-flex:auto;
    -moz-flex:auto;
    -moz-box-flex:auto;
    -ms-flex:auto;
    flex:auto;
    width: auto;
    background: none;
    border:none;
    display: inline-block;
     width: 100%;
}
```

not showing proper into the device.

Comment: menu look like this into iphone : 
https://www.freeonlinephotoeditor.com/tmp/img-59306d6ae87a4/step0001.jpg?1496346171664

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help you troubleshoot or help you in the codes you provide.** Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how/where to post questions. Please add your code.